# How to extract date value from a Dataframe object field

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have read a json file and store it in a dataframe.

When I execute

```
df1.dtypes
```

I obtain tha the field storing the date is unplug_hourTime     object

If I show the forst record using:

```
df1.unplug_hourTime.head(1)
```

I obtain:

```
0    {'$date': '2017-04-01T01:00:00.000+0200'}
Name: unplug_hourTime, dtype: object
```

I'm not sure how can I extract the date from this structure

I would like to have a variable storing 01/04/2017

I have also tried:

```
df1['Dia'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.unplug_hourTime)
```

but error is retrieved:

```
TypeError: <class 'dict'> is not convertible to datetime
```

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete minimal example that we can copy-paste into a REPL to help debug? Can you provide code for manually constructing a similar dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need:

```
df1['Dia'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.unplug_hourTime.apply(lambda x: x['$date'])).dt.date
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand your `dict` into columns like so:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop("unplug_hourTime").tolist()))
```

This will result in this being added to your DataFrame:

```
                          $date
0  2017-04-01T01:00:00.000+0200
```

Then make the resultant Series a datetime:

```
df['Dia'] = pd.to_datetime(df['$date'])
```